# Use LetsEncrypt certs with Neo4j

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, lets-encrypt, neo4j

How can one use the certificate files generated by LetsEncrypt together with a Neo4j instance? The files generated by LetsEncrypt are:

- cert.pem
- chain.pem
- fullchain.pem
- privkey.pem

I've tried [conversion via OpenSSL](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html) with no luck so far, using conversion from PEM to DER. Neo4j complains about not finding the certs upon start. The question is how to convert the LetsEncrypt certs into something that Neo4j can use.

Setup details:

- The certs are placed in `/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/` with names `neo4j.{cert,key}`, permissions `600`, owned by `neo4j:nogroup`. All of this seems to be according to [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/server/https/).
- In the config I have this line to specify the certificate path: `dbms.directories.certificates=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates`
- In the config I also have remote access over HTTPS enabled: `dbms.connector.https.address=0.0.0.0:7473`

When restarting Neo4j I get the following error message:

```
WARN  Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@5a260174[p=1,l=193,c=8192,r=192]={\x16<<< SEVERAL_LINES_OF_HEX_JIBBERISH_HERE }
WARN  badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x16 for HttpChannelOverHttp@5d682358{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

Comment: **At least** you should provide the errors you're getting...

Comment: Good point. Error message and clarifications are now added.

Comment: Note, that according to documentation, you need to convert only key.
For cert just use fullchain.pem

Comment: Using the fullchain for the cert did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to use the lets encrypt certificate on neo4j by using the following process:

- Used the [letsencrypt/acme client implemented as a shell-script](https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated) method to make the certificate for my domain.
- Three files are generated running the script to get the certificate **fullchain.pem** **cert.pem** **privkey.pem**
- Copy them to the certificates directory of neo4j

  **mv /path_to_lets_encrypt_certs_dir/fullchain.pem /var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.cert**

  **mv /path_to_lets_encrypt_certs_dir/privkey.pem /var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.key**
- Restart neo4j

> ```
> anirudh@prok:~# /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j restart
> Stopping Neo4j.. stopped
> Starting Neo4j.
> WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended.  See the Neo4j manual.
> Started neo4j (pid 17608). By default, it is available at  https://your-domain:7473/
> There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
> See /var/lib/neo4j/logs/neo4j.log for current status.
> ```

This should run it for you.
Hope this helps!